# Any debugfs command to set file capability?

Tags: linux, files, attributes

I need an executable inside an ext2 loop filesystem to have the CAP_NET_ADMIN (cap_net_admin) file capability set.

If it is possible with debugfs, what exactly would be the commands I would type in?

If not possible with debugfs, is there another tool or way to do this?

This would be equivalent to the libcap command:
setcap cap_net_admin+ep {executable}

Comment: No, debugfs cannot do this. Why not simply mount it and do it on the mounted filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

I need to do this without root and within a Makefile or script.

Found patches that may go into the next version of debugfs which works great!

Especially the ability to dump out to an outfile (ea_get {file} security.capability -f {outfile}) the known security.capability values of a preset file.

Then you use ea_set (ea_set {file} security.capability -f {infile}) to set any other files to the preset capability.

I think you also need to set before you start if it is not there:

feature ext_attr

Patches will require your hands to get dirty, but it starts from:

http://lists.openwall.net/linux-ext4/2014/03/02/1